# How can I build and manage a Multi-Cluster/Node using both VPSs and large Cloud Providers (like AWS or GCP)?

Tags: kubernetes, devops

**The issue:**
I need an auto scaling solution and this is not being provided by my VPS hosting provider, because I need to buy each VPS manually. Which means, If I have a lot of traffic on my web app which is running on multiple VPS with a hosting provider, it cannot auto scale, due to manually ordering and configuring each new VPS at a time.

**Why an architecture with VPS and pure Cloud?**
First, only a cloud provider can provide an auto scaling solution.
Secondly, because I have a deal with a VPS provider which can give me access to highly configured machines for a low price per month. It can reduce fees and improve my web app for a better price.
For example with a VPS with 4 cpu, 8gb ram, 200gb ssd, I pay $6/ month.
With the same configuration with GCP it’s approximately $34/month, and AWS $49.94.
The idea is to have VPSs and GCP at the same time, instead of using only GCP, or a multi-cluster system (Ex:GCP & AWS) which can handle only cloud providers.

**The result:**
Using a K8s management system which can handle both private VPSs and a cloud provider, to be able to autoscale on a cloud provider like AWS or GCP when needed in real time. And also be able to add new VPSs manually to the architecture, to reduce cost and effectiveness over time (manually).
If so, when my web app gets more traffic, the cloud architecture will auto scale (ex: with GCP). If this traffic persists, I (myself) can decide to buy new VPSs and add them to the architecture to reduce cost and avoid using GCP or AWS only (which are more expensive).

My web app: node.js, angular, express, loopback, mongodb, firebase, k8s, docker, github, github actions, ubuntu 20.04.

I would really love to hear about your thoughts. I'm new in the DepOps field and I hope I was clear about what I want to do.

Cheers,

Tommy

Comment: I think your question is much too broad and too vague. I would recommending focussing on the first aspects you’re trying to solve, and ask the question specifically. Explain what you’ve tried/researched so far and explain where you’ve got stuck.

Comment: Hi lxg,
Thanks for your message. I have updated my query. Is that better? 
If not, can you explain the methodology and result you would like to get?

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. They will show you how to produce a good questions with a reproducible problem.

Answer (score 0):

From a system perspective, a Kubernetes cluster doesn't care whether all nodes are running on the same infrastructure provider as long as you establish proper network connectivity. On the other hand, distributing your cluster has several clear downsides:

- Increased latency by having to span multiple datacenters
- Increased complexity with an additional VPN connection between the infrastructure providers and ensuring that the right workloads are being moved to the temporarily scaled instances
- Fewer ready-to-use cluster management tools are available as they usually target single infrastructure providers.

Once you've set up the network connectivity, etc., you can run a script that monitors free resources on your VPS nodes and then determine when to start a new GCP-based node (here, you even use ephemeral nodes to save extra money).

Comment: Hi Lukas,
Thanks for your help. Yes, I agree, and that's why we are using Kubernetes. 
The downside list is true and I haven't thought about an increasing latency. 

If I understand properly, there's no current solution which can handle VPS and Cloud together?
If yes, about the solution you're proposing, I thought about a script that monitors free resources on VPS nodes too, but how can I send signals to GCP so that it can auto scale, based on VPS traffic?

Comment: @TommyLambert Yes. You need to write that script yourself. If it determines that you need to scale up in GCP, you can trigger the GCP compute API to starts a new VM and configures it as a node. For this I would use a configuration management solution like ansible.